# min less than current value of variable in group wise dplyr filtering

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df like so

```
check <- read.table(text='material    previousUser    currentUser status  date    originFrame currentFrame
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    1/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    1/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    1/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    2/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    2/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    2/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    3/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    3/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    3/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    4/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    4/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    4/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    5/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    5/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    5/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    1/1/2017
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    1/1/2017
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    1/1/2017
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    2/1/2017
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    2/1/2017
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    2/1/2017
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    3/1/2017
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    3/1/2017
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    3/1/2017
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    4/1/2017
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    4/1/2017
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    4/1/2017
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    5/1/2017
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    5/1/2017
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    5/1/2017
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    1/1/2016
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    1/1/2016
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    1/1/2016
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    2/1/2016
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    2/1/2016
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    2/1/2016
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    3/1/2016
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    3/1/2016
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    3/1/2016
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    4/1/2016
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    4/1/2016
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    4/1/2016
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    5/1/2016
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    5/1/2016
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    5/1/2016
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    1/1/2017
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    1/1/2017
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    1/1/2017
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    2/1/2017
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    2/1/2017
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    2/1/2017
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    3/1/2017
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    3/1/2017
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    3/1/2017
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    4/1/2017
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    4/1/2017
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    4/1/2017
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2017-1  1/1/2017    5/1/2017
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2017-2  2/1/2017    5/1/2017
104 Carl    customer    sent    2017-4  4/1/2017    5/1/2017', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
check[c('originFrame','currentFrame')] <- lapply(check[c('originFrame','currentFrame')], as.Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
```

I want to filter, grouped by the currentFrame and material, for the row whose originFrame is equal to the currentFrame, if it isn't equal, then select the maximum originFrame that is less than the currentFrame, like so:

```
material    previousUser    currentUser status  date    originFrame currentFrame
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    1/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    2/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    3/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    4/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    5/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  4/1/2016    1/1/2017
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  4/1/2016    2/1/2017
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  4/1/2016    3/1/2017
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    4/1/2017
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    5/1/2017
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2017    1/1/2016
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  1/1/2017    2/1/2016
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  1/1/2017    3/1/2016
104 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  1/1/2017    4/1/2016
104 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  1/1/2017    5/1/2016
104 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2017    1/1/2017
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2017    2/1/2017
104 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2017    3/1/2017
104 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2017    4/1/2017
104 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2017    5/1/2017
```

This works but does not take into account the value of the currentFrame and thus gives me the wrong results

```
check <- as.data.frame(
  check %>% 
    group_by(currentFrame, material) %>% 
    filter(
      ifelse(
        currentFrame %in% originFrame,
        originFrame == currentFrame,
        ifelse(
          max(originFrame) > currentFame,
          originFrame == max(originFrame),
          originFrame == max(originFrame)
        )
      )
    )
)
```

but I can't seem to get it work with rule that the max must be below the value of the currentFrame using the following which returns the wrong number of observations

```
check <- as.data.frame(
  check %>% 
    group_by(currentFrame, material) %>% 
    filter(
      ifelse(
        currentFrame %in% originFrame,
        originFrame == currentFrame,
        ifelse(
          max(originFrame) > currentFrame,
          originFrame == which.max(originFrame < currentFrame),
          originFrame == max(originFrame)
        )
      )
    )
)
```

Edit* should mention, actualy datafame contains many materials with different dates, updating now

Edit2* alright, sorry, hopefully that is more clear, if anyone has any feedback on how I could of worded this question better I would appreciate that.

Comment: can you `dput(df)` and replace the first description of `df` with that?  While showing us data is nice, we can actually USE `dput` rather easily.

Comment: Thanks Jake I will use that next time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out,

What I ended up doing is splitting the data frame into three data frames, one for originFrame = CurrentFrame, originFrame < currentFrame, originFrame > currentFrame. I then removed everything that was dataframe 1, from dataframe 2, and everything that was in dataframe 1 and 2 from data frame 3, I then took the max originFrame from dataframe2, and the min originFrame from dataframe3. After binding them back together I had what I needed.

Comment: If you're going to submit and accept your own answer, at least make it something usable (with sample code) and *reproducible*.

Answer (score 1):

Your data, in a more-consumable format:

```
check <- read.table(text='material    previousUser    currentUser status  date    originFrame currentFrame
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    1/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    1/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    1/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    2/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    2/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    2/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    3/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    3/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    3/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    4/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    4/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    4/1/2016
123 inventory   Dave    draft   2016-1  1/1/2016    5/1/2016
123 Dave    Carl    transfer    2016-2  2/1/2016    5/1/2016
123 Carl    customer    sent    2016-4  4/1/2016    5/1/2016', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
check[c('originFrame','currentFrame')] <- lapply(check[c('originFrame','currentFrame')], as.Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
```

One way, continuing with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
check %>%
  mutate(datediff = currentFrame - originFrame) %>%
  arrange(currentFrame, datediff)  %>%
  group_by(currentFrame) %>%
  filter(datediff >= 0) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-datediff)
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   material previousUser currentUser   status   date originFrame currentFrame
#      <int>        <chr>       <chr>    <chr>  <chr>      <date>       <date>
# 1      123    inventory        Dave    draft 2016-1  2016-01-01   2016-01-01
# 2      123         Dave        Carl transfer 2016-2  2016-02-01   2016-02-01
# 3      123         Dave        Carl transfer 2016-2  2016-02-01   2016-03-01
# 4      123         Carl    customer     sent 2016-4  2016-04-01   2016-04-01
# 5      123         Carl    customer     sent 2016-4  2016-04-01   2016-05-01
```

Comment: Hey r2evans, this works on my example but my actual dataframe has many different materials with different dates. When I run the code I only get 1 observation for each current frame. If I add materials to the group_by I get more observations but I am missing rows.

I am missing rows where where the material group hasn't had a originFrame = to the currentFrame, so I only get the rows starting from the first originFrame onward to the end of the currentFrame.

Comment: There's not much I can do based on just that. You'll need to edit your question, and add data that is more-representative and which demonstrates this problem you are experiencing.

Comment: I thought the `arrange` part was necessary, which is why I went the explicit route. However, my guess is that your code-golf version will also not work with the actual data. More to come if/when we see more-representative data.

Comment: Added more, hope that is more clear, thanks for the feedback